# Strange effect happening when adding CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a webpage which worked well until I added the following HTML and CSS around it:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <!-- old HTML within these 2 div tags worked find before adding these 2 new div tags -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content
{
    background:#BBBBBB;
}

.inner_content
{
    width:993px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    background:#AAAAAA;
}
```

**Strange effect:**

You can see the "strange effect" happening in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrpGr/2/).

If you click any div which contains a `(c)`, you will notice a little dropdown appear.  If you then attempt to move a widget by dragging the header of the widget, watch what happens to the dropdown that appeared by clicking the `(c)`

This didn't happen before I added the above HTML and CSS.

**Screenshots:**

Here are some screenshots to show the problem:

Dropdown looks fine here:
[image]
[Click to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHHa7.png)

Moving widget with dropdown enabled with old HTML, dropdown moves correctly with widget:
[image]
[Click to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGlLq.png)

Moving widget with dropdown enabled with new divs/css added, dropwdown moves incorrectly with widget:
[image]
[Click to enlarge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXuXk.png)

**Question:**

Is there a way to correct it without losing the effect the HTML and CSS adds to the page, without causing the dropdown to do strange things?

Comment: I watch, but I don't see different "strange effects" with or without the outer two divs. Can you describe the differences better?

Comment: Same her (google chrome). The dropdown stays open and stays neatly inline with the moved box.

Comment: It appears when you drop the div with drop-down open. But maybe the simplest solution, collapse the dropdown in the drag-init. We won't need it while dragging, so why show it?

Comment: I'll take some screenshots.  Need a few moments.  Thanks.

Comment: @Neograph734 That the dropdowns are drawn in a different position when dragging? Yes, but that's the also the case without the outer two divs.

Comment: I've added 3 screenshots, 1. shows default position which is correct, 2. shows moving widget without new HTML and CSS, dropdown is correct, 3. shows moving widget with new HTML and CSS, dropdown is incorrect.

Comment: @Neograph734, I was thinking about using the disappearing solution if all else failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start dragging the `.widget`, jQuery-UI adds a style of `position: absolute;` to that `.widget` element which is removed when dragging stops. That's what's causing the dropdown to jump position.

To fix, add `position: relative;` (`position: absolute;` will also work) to the styles for `.widget` and re-evaluate your positioning arithmetic. I would suggest:

```
$dd.css({
    top: $nav3.outerHeight()+10,
    right: 10
});
```

You may need to increase the `z-index` of `.dropdown` as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/RrpGr/14/

There are many other optimizations that can be done, but this should be sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: Seems to work nicely in IE8 and Google Chrome.  Trying this out in my main project and will report back shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: Just found an issue with this.  Clicking on `(c)` on the top row of widgets is almost perfect, but clicking on the `(c)` in the bottom row of widgets seems to open the dropdown off the screen.  All the dropdowns should have their top-right corner aligned with the bottom-right corner of their respective `(c)`s.

Comment: That works, thanks. My only issue is that your example seems to have created `.widgets` which have z-index's higher than all other elements on the page. I have a few other different `.dropdown`s above the HTML I posted in the original question, and those dropdowns go behind these widgets. Even if I set the widgets to 1 and the external dropdowns to 1000. They still go behind the widgets. I'll start another question for this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you can adjust all the z-indices as you need. I just picked a large enough number for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the padding you give the one div.

Your Dropdown positions relative to an element. When you start dragging it around, the dropdown positions relative to another element.

Overall I find your HTML and CSS quite messy, but here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RrpGr/3/

I removed overflow: hidden from the .widget_header as its sole purpose was to contain the floating elements (right?) and instead added an pseudo-element which clears the floats.

```
.widget_header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Additionally I removed quite a few lines from your Javascript. These where only to set CSS properties (or calculate the values).

I don't see why you can't just position the dropdown relative to the .widget_header (that is what I did)?

Comment: IE8 doesn't seem to like this, if I click the `(c)`, the dropdown doesn't appear until I mouseout of the `(c)`.  However, your example does fix the moving problem.